# iPhone Unit Testing

Tags: iphone, unit-testing

I finished my project on an iPhone dev at uni WITHOUT doing "useful" unit testing (did some simple ones just to put on my report).

I was looking at the apple's unit testing suits (logic and application tests) but ended up using iPhoneUnitTesting from google-toolbox-for-mac, which I found more documented and easy to get started with Java's unit testing knowledge.

1. How many of you actually use this rather than the Apple's "native" unit testing suits?
2. Any suggestions for books on this topic (unit testing for iPhone)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have a series on [iPhone Unit Testing](http://paulsolt.com/2010/11/iphone-unit-testing-explained-part-1/). Initially, I explored OCUnit (Xcode), Google Toolbox for Mac (GTM) and GHUnit. Testing wise, I prefer the Xcode built in unit tests (OCUnit). Visually I prefer GHUnit for the GUI interface. Xcode 4's testing support is much improved from Xcode 3.

If you need a GUI on the device for testing, you can add GHUnit later, since it is built on top of GTM and can run OCUnit and GTM unit tests.

### iPhone Unit Testing Explained

- [iPhone Unit Testing Explained Part I](http://paulsolt.com/2010/11/iphone-unit-testing-explained-part-1/)
- [iPhone Unit Testing Explained Part II](http://paulsolt.com/2012/03/iphone-unit-testing-explained-part-ii/)

Comment: Thanks Paul, I just managed to find time for you post. Very helpful and I'll definitely give a try on GHUnit. The workflow you put at the end is a nice note too! Cheers!!!

Comment: Nice articles! Looks like the part I links to part II are broken, and part II promises a part III. IS that anywhere?

Comment: Links work for me, I haven't had time to publish the last part III.

Answer (score 7):

You might find these links useful:

- [Test Driving Your Code with OCUnit](http://developer.apple.com/tools/unittest.html)
- [Automated Unit Testing with Xcode 3 and Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/mac/articles/tools/unittestingwithxcode3.html)
- [OCUnit: Integrated Unit Testing In Xcode](http://www.mobileorchard.com/ocunit-integrated-unit-testing-in-xcode/)
- [iPhone Unit Testing with OCUnit](http://6tringle.com/blog/2009/iPhoneUnitTesting.html)

Answer (score 3):

i use GHUnit, is a test framework for Objective-C, you can follow the instruction on the page or see the video [TDD for iPhone Development](http://www.vimeo.com/16722907) , GHUnit  it's easy to use and very helpful.

cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I found OCUnit really straightforward and easy to use. Very similar to JUnit or other unit testing modules for other languages.

Comment: Thanks for one vote for OCUnit, yeah I find it easy(iest) to learn as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the updated URL for :
 [Apple's Automated Testing With Xcode 3 and Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/UnitTestingXcode3/)