# Are there any standard practices for organising files within an iOS xCode project?

Tags: ios, xcode4

I'm coming to iOS development from a web dev background.

Having all of my view controllers, data models and storyboards in the same directory is a real mess.

Are there any conventions for organising files within a project?

If not, are there any good reasons why I shouldn't do so like:

```
my_project/
  view_controllers/
  data_models/
  views/
  assets/
  tests/
```

All advice appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no conventions (that I know of at least), it just comes down to what you feel move comfortable with. I use a similar kind of structure to you though along these lines:

```
MyProject/
  Source/
    Controller/
    Model/
    View/
    External/
      JoeRandomLibrary/
  Resources/
    Graphics/
    Interfaces/
```

I find that lays things out quite nicely. I then replicate that structure to that on disk as well.

Comment: I see you haven't included tests here... how common is unit testing in the iOS world?

Comment: @bodacious A great question! I don't tend to unit test probably as much as I should, to be honest. I sometimes do but find user testing is much better in my experience. There's lots of questions about it though on here, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621617/unit-testing-for-the-app-store

Comment: Interesting... but also a load off my mind for now - I'm usually quite strict with TDD but can't even think where I'd start in iOS